# Is std::array iterator typedef implementation defined

Tags: c++, stl

Is the iterator type requirement for std::array<T,N>::iterator implementation defined or is it always defined to be a pointer to value_type?

Comment: It's always a pointer, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Unlike for `std::vector`.

Comment: @yeputons Funny, I was going to link to that exact same page to claim that it's implementation-defined. "LegacyRandomAccessIterator, contiguous_iterator, and ConstexprIterator to value_type " does not mean it has to be a pointer.

Comment: Indeed there would be an advantage to keeping this implementation-defined: implementations could use a wrapper type to validate dereferences in debug mode, as a debugging aid.

Comment: @Thomas Ah, yes, misread that. Definitely implementation-defined at the very least: `std::array<int, 5>::iterator` is a class in my Visual Studio, coincides with [that code](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/8ddf4da23939b5c65587ed05f783ff39b8801e0f/stl/inc/array#L417-L418).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implementation-defined.

See the [C++20 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) (working draft, the final version costs money), section 22.3.7, "Class template `array`":

```
namespace std {
template<class T, size_t N>
struct array {
    // types
    ...
    using iterator = implementation-defined ; // see 22.2
    using const_iterator = implementation-defined ; // see 22.2
    ...
};
```